# Uncountably many left ideals?

Tags: ideals, noncommutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a following subring of $M_2(\mathbb{C}):$
\begin{equation*}
R = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
                   a & r \\
                   0 & s
\end{bmatrix} ~:~ a\in \mathbb{Q} ~\mbox{and}~r,s \in \mathbb{C} 
\right\}.
\end{equation*}

(a) Prove that $R$ is both right Noetherian and right Artinian.
(b) Prove that $R$ has uncountable many left ideals.
(c) Is $R$ left Noetherian? Is $R$ left Artinian?

According to me:
The right ideals are
\begin{equation*}
\left\{ 
I_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
I_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & r \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
I_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
a & r \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, 
I_4 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & r \\
0 & s
\end{bmatrix},
I_5 = \begin{bmatrix}
a & r \\
0 & s
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}.
\end{equation*}
and the left ideals are
\begin{equation*}
\left\{ 
I_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
I_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & r \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
I_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
a & r \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, 
I_4 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & r \\
0 & s
\end{bmatrix},
I_5 = \begin{bmatrix}
a & r \\
0 & s
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}.
\end{equation*}
How from here I should say show (a) and (b) and (c) ?
For (a) I think
\begin{equation}
I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq I_3 \subseteq I_5 \quad or \quad I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq I_3 \subseteq I_5
\end{equation}
are the only possible chians and they stablizes and for Artinian I think reverse order works?? But I dont see why there should be uncountably many left ideals? What is that I am not seeing? I am not very good at Noetherian and Artinian rings. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For $r\in\Bbb C$ let

$$I_r=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&br\\0&0\end{bmatrix}:a,b\in\Bbb Q\right\}\;.$$

If

$$\begin{bmatrix}c&s\\0&t\end{bmatrix}\in R\quad\text{and}\quad\begin{bmatrix}a&br\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\in I_r\;,$$

then

$$\begin{bmatrix}c&s\\0&t\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&br\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ac&(bc)r\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\in I_r\;,$$

so $I_r$ is a left ideal of $R$. For $w,z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ write $w\sim z$ iff $\frac{w}z\in\Bbb Q$; $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$, and $I_w=I_z$ iff $w\sim z$. Each $\sim$-equivalence class is countable, and $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is uncountable, so there are uncountably many (in fact $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$) $\sim$-classes and hence uncountably many left ideals of $R$.

Comment: Thank You. But I am confused about why a similar argument doesn't work for right ideals?

Comment: @Kumarm: You’re welcome. I didn’t look at right ideals, but I suspect that you’ll have a hard time finding an analogue of $I_r$.